# Weblogic datasource configuration for DB on Oracle Dataguard with PDB

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, dataguard

We are moving to Oracle Dataguard with PDB.

Currently we just point to a single DB url in Weblogic datasource configuration.

How to configure the Datasource in weblogic for Oracle Dataguard with PDB ?
Should we use 'JDBC Multi Datasource' ?

Comment: Oracle's GridLink Datasource are best suited for using DataGuard with WebLogic Server : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/gridlink_datasources.htm#JDBCA373

Comment: Thanks. We don't use ORAC and only Dataguard with PDB..

Comment: GridLinks works fine with DataGuard also. RAC is not mandatory at all.

Comment: Thanks I would try that

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Many thanks ..you are Brilliant. It worked.. Thanks for the help and giving me the confidence..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by @Emmanuel Collin in the comments has the complete details.

And for those who need short answer, in weblogic server I have created a 'GridLink Data Source' and added the multiple DB server configuration details.

And the DB connection URL came out like below. And it worked fine.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@
    (DESCRIPTION=
        (
            ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
                (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_DB_SERVER1)(PORT=1521))
                (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_DB_SERVER2)(PORT=1521))
        )
        (
            CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SERVICE)
        )
    )
```